# Is there any way to close other tabs which opened by js in IE....?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, window.open

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close</button>
<script> 
var myWindow;
function openWin() {
myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", "width=500, height=500");}
function closeWin() {
myWindow.close();}

</script>
```

it can not be closed when I entered the url in window.open...

any Ideas of this???

Much Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: this script works on chrome but ie..

Answer (score 0):

```
    myWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com", "width=500, height=500");
```

Comment: um...I think this is not what I want.. for example... page a: window.open, the new page called page b... and page a there is a button which called close and click it to close page b..

Comment: reopen the page through of the Ctrl + Shift + T shortcut in Chrome. So the page will runn, but without a parent window reference, and because this can't be closed.

Comment: oh..I found that the reason what I have fail to close with myWindow.close();..... it can be close the website with the same domain only..